# Site got taken out of the search engines almost entirely

Tags: seo

I have a new site (just over 3 months old) and after a month or so, it started ranking for some searches in Google.

Then suddenly after 2 months, boom, no traffic coming from search other than when people search for the name of the site.

My question is whether this is something common? I was doing some link-building, but nothing too out of whack. I did 2 guest posts on some blogs.

Comment: -1 The question in your post - "My question is whether this is something common?" - does not meet the quality guidelines for a question (see [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)). Please consider rephrasing your question - e.g. "Can guest blogging negatively affect Google ranking?"

Comment: -1 Cause v Correlation. This question is _way_ too vague to substantiate a helpful answer. To get an accurate answer, we'd need to get a list of EVERY activity you've conducted since the site was built.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the [Google sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect): for a certain period of time, Google try to reduce traffic to your website to see how it will survive. After that, everything should return to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing to worry, when you launch a site it get index and google sends you some traffic but slowly it goes down when it checks for the ranking factors. I would suggest if you want to good traffic start blogging at least twice a week and do more link building.

Answer (score -3):

New Google Panda update is really taking the below issue serious:

- if you are linking to a site with 4 to 5 adsense within the site, then you're gonna penalized.

New update is about 1 week old. I think you should be careful to whom you are linking to.

Comment: Do you have a reliable source for that?

Comment: Yes, you can go to www.searchEngineWatch.com and then look for recent panda updates.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about [this page](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2067687/Google-Panda-Update-Say-Goodbye-to-Low-Quality-Link-Building). For starters I wouldn't call a search blog 'reliable' personally, but ignoring that the article itself says "...Google *may* have or eventually deem..." ie they don't know, they are just guessing.